# Select2 not working on generated elements by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am using [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) in my project. My issue is that `select2:select`event is not working on generated elements by JS.

I have created this snippet so you can test what I say.

```js
var i = 0,
  data = [
     { 
       id: 0, 
        text: 'Bob' 
      },
      { 
       id: 1, 
        text: 'Martin' 
      },
      { 
       id: 2, 
        text: 'John' 
      }
  ];
    $('#in-9').select2({
     data: data
    });
    
    // Button click event
$('#append').on('click', function () {
 var html = '<p><label for="in-' + i + '">Select2 #' + i + ':</label><br><input id="in-' + i + '" class="in"><br></p>';
  
  // Append HTML to Body
 $('body').append(html);
  
  // Assign data to input
  $('#in-' + i).select2({
   data: data
  });
  
  // Increase counter
  i++;
 
});

// Trigger "select" on select2 only works in first element.
$('.in').on('select2:select', function() {
 alert('wii');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<button id="append">Append to Body</button>

<!-- First element -->
<p>
  <label for="in-9'">Select2 #9:</label><br>
  <input id="in-9" class="in"><br>
</p>
```

You can see in the fiddle the HTML element with `id="in-9"` is created in the HTML but when clicking on `Append to Body` a Javascript function is called and the generated elements can't trigger the `select2:select` event like the first one.

So my question is, how I can call the `select2:select` event on the dynamically generated elements?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki and @DavidR, actually this is not duplicated because in that post he asks to initialize the dynamically generated elements, I am asking to trigger the `select2:select` event on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method!

> The `.on()` method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements or dynamically generated elements in the jQuery object

You can try this:

```
$('body').on('select2:select', '.in', function() {
    alert('wii');
});
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
var i = 0,
  data = [
     { 
       id: 0, 
        text: 'Bob' 
      },
      { 
       id: 1, 
        text: 'Martin' 
      },
      { 
       id: 2, 
        text: 'John' 
      }
  ];
    $('#in-9').select2({
     data: data
    });
    
    // Button click event
$('#append').on('click', function () {
 var html = '<p><label for="in-' + i + '">Select2 #' + i + ':</label><br><input id="in-' + i + '" class="in"><br></p>';
  
  // Append HTML to Body
 $('body').append(html);
  
  // Assign data to input
  $('#in-' + i).select2({
   data: data
  });
  
  // Increase counter
  i++;
 
});

// Trigger "select" on select2 only works in first element.
$('body').on('select2:select', '.in', function() {
 alert('wii');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<button id="append">Append to Body</button>

<!-- First element -->
<p>
  <label for="in-9'">Select2 #9:</label><br>
  <input id="in-9" class="in"><br>
</p>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What should he put in the callback function? Maybe something like `$('#in-' + i).select2();`?

Comment: It worked, thank you. I thought I already tried something like that but it seems I didn't.

Comment: My please, glad that it works for you!

Comment: helped me to make it work!